# Format Firestore timestamps in BigQuery SQL for Data Studio

Tags: sql, google-cloud-firestore, google-bigquery, looker-studio

We're importing our Firestore data into BigQuery to generate reports in Data Studio.

Following works for SQL timestamps, but not for Firestore-JSON timestamps.

```
SELECT 
    PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%Y%m%d', JSON_VALUE(`data`, "$.updated_at")) AS `updated_at`
FROM 
    `project.firestore_export.profiles_raw_latest`
```

Our dates are in a Firestore `timestamp` format in the column `data` in a JSON field called `updated_at`.

How do I get a usable date format to ultimately use in Data Studio?

*Edit:* When I query the field without `JSON_VALUE` it returns as `null`, it's a standard timestamp format in Firestore. When I preview the data in BigQuery it returns as a JSON object: `{"_seconds":1569585420,"_nanoseconds":586000000}`

Comment: Can you share an example of one?

Comment: @GrahamPolley When I query the field without `JSON_VALUE` it returns as `null`, it's a standard timestamp format in Firestore. When I preview the data in BigQuery it returns as a JSON object: `{"_seconds":1569585420,"_nanoseconds":586000000}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you don't need subsecond precision, then you can use:

```
#standardSQL
with sample_table as (
  select '{"_seconds":1569585420,"_nanoseconds":586000000}' as ts
  )
select PARSE_DATETIME("%s", JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(ts, "$['_seconds']"))
from sample_table;
```

Output:

```
+---------------------+
|         f0_         |
+---------------------+
| 2019-09-27T11:57:00 |
+---------------------+
```

If you do need more precision in your timestamp, you can use [timestamp_micros()](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/timestamp_functions#timestamp_micros).

Comment: When I use this to query the data with the `DS` parameters in the `WHERE` clause I get an error `WHERE PARSE_DATETIME("%s", JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(`data`, "$.created_at._seconds")) > PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%Y%m%d', @DS_START_DATE)` which states `No matching signature for operator >`

Comment: You cannot compare a DATETIME and a TIMESTAMP, make both PARSE_ DATETIME or TIMESTAMP.